# Word processing software or other text-based tool that can "find" text with complex formatting

Tags: text-processing, text-search, clipboard, word-processor, formatter

Follow up to my question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1656343/in-ms-word-can-you-use-advanced-find-to-match-formatted-text-copied-to-the-clip/1656535), I'm looking for word processing software or other text-based tool that can "find" text with complex (ie. formats not applied to the entire string) formatting, preferably from the clipboard.

For example, I would like to be able to copy some text to the clipboard like this:

[image]

And then use a Find function to match, in another document:

[image]

but not:

[image]

MS Word, for example, in its advanced find function, can only find strings with formatting applied to the entire string.